# Can't install or find python-pip and python-requests using sudo apt-get install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I tried installing python-requests earlier using

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-requests
```

and I get

```
Unable to locate package python-requests
```

I know this is a common question, but I've tried everything I could find: I ensured I have all repositories enable (Main, universe, etc.). Next, I tried installing python-pip in order to use pip instead of apt, but I got the same error when trying to install python-pip as with python-requests. After that, I used

```
sudo apt-cache search python-requests
sudo apt-cache search python-pip
```

to try to see if I had the name wrong or something, but could not locate either. I tried installing

```
 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

as some stackoverflow question recommended in addition to running 
`sudo apt-get update` many times. Additionally, I ensured that my standard 
`python` does indeed point to python-2.7. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my version is 20.04 and yes, I have Universe repository and all other possible repositories enabled.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `python-requests` was dropped from Ubuntu after 19.10. However, `python3-requests` is still in Ubuntu (Main).

The package `python-pip` is also still in Ubuntu (Universe)